# How to prepare new stucco, for a later heavy duty item attachment?

Tags: waterproofing, stucco

I would like to hang a particular heavy duty hose reel on a wall that will be patched with stucco.  In other words, it's sheathing and studs right now.

I could wait until after the stucco is on, drill holes overly large, caulk, and insert a screw.  But can I do better?  Is there some form of stud that could be placed in the stucco or on the wall, that offers less risk of long term water barrier failure?

This is USA West Coast, 1938 stucco wood frame home.

Comment: If the wall is open, why would you not just place 2 x 4 wood framing member(s) across the stud bay, so you could screw into solid wood, prior to stuccoing?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly 'Trex' block build-outs to stucco up against.  The blocks would set proud of the stucco finish surface a bit.  Secure the blocks  to the sheathing and on into a stud and or 2x4 backing.  I would cut an octagonal or diamond shaped block for appearance. Paint it the same color as the stucco.

Another option would be a pattern of threaded rod anchors. (Sammy) Fill the thread to keep clean.

Comment: You might clarify what "fill the thread" means. Who's Sammy?

Comment: I'd also suggest drip cap (flashing) over the mounting block.

Answer (score 0):

Google just found me a "hanger bolt" from a Florida hurricane information website:

[image: Hanger Bolt for Shutters]

Looks like these models would have to be only partially screwed in.  The stucco would come right up to the metal. which could cause leaks over time if the metal rusts.

Comment: Nails can rust out.  I have a 1938 house where the original nails holding the downspout rusted out, probably bit by bit, over 80 years.  Water then wicked in along the nails.....